# digitalRead influenced by touches

Tags: arduino-uno

```
  const int BUTTON      = 8;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
}



void loop() {

  Serial.println(digitalRead(BUTTON));

}
```

I have connected a cable to pin 8. It's not connected to anything else nor have I any other cables connected.
I am expecting constant zeros, but I keep getting ones and zeros all the time, e.g. when shortly touching the cable.

I didn't experience that before. Did I accidentally damage my Arduino?

Comment: Why are you expecting constant zeros? Do you have a pulldown on the pin? Unconnected inputs are undefined, unless something is driving the pin it'll float around at random. A person is a good 50/60 Hz antenna and so when you touch the wire you'll get random noise.

Comment: Google the phrase "Floating Input"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't connect it to anything, it can be a result of a flipping 'input' ... try to use a pullup or pulldown resistor.

Or better:

[PullUp](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/InputPullupSerial)

Use something like:

```
 pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Answer (score 2):

The pin is floating. Use pull up or pull down to help define its logic state.